# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 wont get fixed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying for over 2 hours now trying to figure out what's wrong with this database. I've tried everything. From reinstalling the server, restarting the processes, rebooting and so much more. It keeps giving me this error when trying to connect:

```
const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:797:32)
    at D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:330:10
    at D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1151:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:329:20)
    at module.exports (D:\TheShed\MX_\other\DB\mong.js:4:20)
    at D:\TheShed\MX_\app.js:195:37
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\TheShed\MX_\app.js:197:3) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1421094,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\TheShed\MX_\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:267:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

This error wont resolve no matter what I do. The MongoDB server is running, I've checked by doing >show dbs and it lists them perfectly fine. Also, C:/data/db exists and its fine too.
What do I do?
Here's my connection code:

```
(async () => {
    await require('./other/DB/mong')();
    console.log("Connected to Database.");
})();
```

and here's ./other/DB/mong:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/MX', {
        keepAlive: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    return mongoose;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using latest nodejs (v17.x) , update the mongodb url from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Me too! How strange, I'd been using it fine all day, started a new project and suddenly had to implement this change: many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not bind to localhost on ipv6 by default.

If you want it to listen on ::1 you will need to enable [net.ipv6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.ipv6) and either enable [net.bindIpAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.bindIpAll) or explicitly list the loopback address in [net.bindIp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.bindIp)

Answer (score 1):

Updated my mongodb url from 'mongodb://localhost:27017/student' to 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/student' and it worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {

    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
    autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
    maxPoolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Keep trying to send operations for 5 seconds
    socketTimeoutMS: 45000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
    family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
}
```

Comment: A good answer *explains* how the solution solves the problem. The comments, in your code, only explain what the parameters do, but you don't explain how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `family:4` into the connect method.