# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem when I try to connect my app with my database with Mongoose. Already tried following solutions that I found on google:

- restarting MongoDB service on windows
- manually open db with cmd located on bin file of mongodb

But I can't solve it. Can anyone help me ?

```js
//my connection
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/notes-db-app',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And throw's me , this error

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:797:32)
    at C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:330:10    at C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1151:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:329:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\src\db.js:3:10)      
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10) {      
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

I try to put the port on my connection code like this

```js
//my connection
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notes-db-app',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and it throw's me another error

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Invalid message size: 1347703880, max allowed: 67108864
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:797:32)
    at C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:330:10    at C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1151:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:329:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\NodeJS\notes-app\src\db.js:3:10)      
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10) {      
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:3000' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that Mongodb is running, open task scheduler look for mongo, if You're doing it from linux subsystem so: `ps -ax | grep mongo`

Comment: OP did that already and is using windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 wont get fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763130/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017-wont-get-fixed)

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. Do not edit the question

Answer (score 30):

If the Error states:

> connect() Error :MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Then the connection to **localhost** is refused on the IPv6 address **::1** .
Mongoose per default uses IPv6 ..

For a quick check you can set the IPv4 address explicit:

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test')
```

Comment: awesome! It solved the problem.

Comment: Cool, that actually runs the db connection properly. However, what causes this error? On my laptop, the connection starts with `localhost`, but using my PC, it requires to run it with `127.0.0.1`. I want to find what is not configured properly.

The only difference is that the laptop is using Win10, but the PC is using Win11

Comment: I don't think Mongoose is the culprit. Alias `localhost` is resolved by the operating system

Comment: That's is the correct solution.

Answer (score 10):

Simply pass third parameter `family:4` ie.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/notes-db-app',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    family: 4,
})
```

Answer (score 8):

I finally solved it.

Enabling the IPV6 that MongoDB has disabled by default. Using the following command line on CMD:

```
mongod --ipv6
```

And then try again the connection and it works!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/notes-db-app',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>

Comment: It was exactly more than 2 days I was struggling to figure out what is the problem in my connection then I saw your suggestion I mean using "--ipv6" in mongod command and it was absolutely what I needed, Perfect thanks and really appreciate. actually I edited my command to mongod --dbpath /data/db --replSet "rs" and it works perfectly like a charm. ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
    autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
    maxPoolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Keep trying to send operations for 5 seconds
    socketTimeoutMS: 45000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
    family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
}

const connectWithDB = () => {
    mongoose.connect(uri, options, (err, db) => {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      else console.log("database connection")
    })
}

connectWithDB()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, the `localhost` alias resolves to IPv6 address `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`

However, [`net.ipv6`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.ipv6) defaults to `false`.

The best option would be to start the MongoDB with this configuration:

```
net:
  ipv6: true
  bindIpAll: true
```

or

```
net:
  ipv6: true
  bindIp: localhost
```

Then all variants will work:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

mongoose.connect('mongodb://[::1]:27017',{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${os.hostname()}:27017`,{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

If you don't run MongoDB as a service then it would be

```
mongod --bind_ip_all --ipv6 <other options>
```

NB, I don't like configuration

```
net:
  bindIp: <ip_address>
```

in my opinion this makes only sense on a computer with multiple network interfaces however, MongoDB [does not support multiple interfaces](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1889). Use `bindIp: localhost` if you need to prevent any connections from remote computer (e.g. while maintenance or when used as backend database for a web-service), otherwise use `bindIpAll: true`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the hostname/IP of the server to which you want to connect is not correctly set. 
I'm used to see that error as:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED <hostname/hostIP>:<port>
```

and in the console log you've posted, the `<hostname/hostIP>` part is malformed/missing.

*Example* - for a mongodb server running **locally** on port **27017** this is the error when server is down:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

If you're using mongodb URI to connect to the db make sure that it looks like this

```
"mongodb://<hostname/hostIP>:<port>"
```

Comment: The <hostname/hostIP> part is not malformed/missing. `::1` is the normal IPv6 loopback address.

Answer (score -3):

1. Open your terminal and type this command: `mongod`
2. Then use your app.js to establish a connection by writing this code :

   ```
   const mongoose=require("mongoose");
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/notes-db-app',{
       useNewUrlParser: true, 
       useUnifiedTopology: true,
       family: 4,
   })
   ```
3. It's done now. Simply open your mongo shell or your mongodb compass and look for whatever you have added.