# Error: Unable to connect to MongoDB server on localhost:27017 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-connection

Title: Unable to establish connection with MongoDB server: MongooseServerSelectionError

Description:
When running the following code to connect to a MongoDB server using Mongoose:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb").then(() => {
    console.log("Connection Successful");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Something went wrong!", error);
});
I encounter the following error:
"Something went wrong! MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (d:\DB Server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (d:\DB Server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}"
```

Issue:
I am unable to establish a connection with the MongoDB server. The code attempts to connect to the MongoDB database specified in the connection string (mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb), but it throws the MongooseServerSelectionError with the message connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017.

What did you try and what were you expecting?
I tried to establish a connection to the MongoDB server using the Mongoose library. I expected the connection to be successful, indicated by the message "Connection Successful" being logged to the console.
What actually resulted?
However, instead of a successful connection, I received an error. The error message displayed "Something went wrong!" followed by the error details, specifically the MongooseServerSelectionError with the message connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017.

Additional Information:

Node.js version: v18.16.0
MongoDB version: 6.0
Operating system: Windows 11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840504/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to MongoDB 6.0 Server locally using Nodejs driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609210/cant-connect-to-mongodb-6-0-server-locally-using-nodejs-driver)