# Cannot Connect Mongoose to Mongodb connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, homebrew

I am having a problem with connecting Mongodb to Express js.
I've tried to reinstall mongodb-community via Homebrew, adding data directory, changing port still get the same error. What should I do?

`server.js` code :

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/handover', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Mongodb connected');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})

app.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log('Server connected on port 3030')
})
```

Error :

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Volumes/SYAR/PROJECTS/CAZAPP/CARHANDOVER/APP/backend/v1/test/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)
    at /Volumes/SYAR/PROJECTS/CAZAPP/CARHANDOVER/APP/backend/v1/test/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:330:10
    at /Volumes/SYAR/PROJECTS/CAZAPP/CARHANDOVER/APP/backend/v1/test/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/SYAR/PROJECTS/CAZAPP/CARHANDOVER/APP/backend/v1/test/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/SYAR/PROJECTS/CAZAPP/CARHANDOVER/APP/backend/v1/test/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1151:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Volumes/SYAR/PROJECTS/CAZAPP/CARHANDOVER/APP/backend/v1/test/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:329:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/SYAR/PROJECTS/CAZAPP/CARHANDOVER/APP/backend/v1/test/server.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

And this is the running service of MongoDB :

```
mongod    7966 syarifmaulana    9u  IPv4 0xb96c3a4a1b6b3315      0t0  TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)
```

And this is the last `mongo.log`

````
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.406+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":15,"error":"Terminated: 15"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.406+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23381,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"will terminate after current cmd ends"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.406+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.407+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.407+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.407+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.408+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784903, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.408+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23017,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"removing socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27019.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.409+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":5093807, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784916, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Reacquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784917, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Attempting to mark clean shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20609,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.410+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684100, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684101, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.411+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.412+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.412+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.412+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.412+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.413+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1636427904:413311][5698:0x700007fae000], close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 50, snapshot max: 50 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 16"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.472+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":60}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.472+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.473+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.473+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.473+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20626,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.479+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-09T10:18:24.479+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":0}}```
````

Comment: Check if you are able to connect to the database server from any other tool like `mongo` shell or Compass. Make sure the server is up and running while you try to connect.

Comment: I checked it and running well, but when I try to connect using mongoose failed.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. I change `localhost` to IP `127.0.0.1` in Mongo URI. And the server connected to Mongo DB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69768987/2282634